# Method scan localisation iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

What is the way to scan and get the people who using the same app around you. I want to create an application who scan 3-4 km around the person to get the list of the user's who use the same app. I just want a track, advices...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be, to save the current location of a user, that uses your app to your own server database. Than you can request your backend with your current position. In your backend you check all coordinates and calculate, if one of your other app users has a coordinate near to the given one. if yes, return those to the client who requested the user-locations near to him.

Comment: Good idea ! Thank you dalipsia